# xparse regression? Unable to create environment with single optional argument

Tags: environments, optional-arguments, xparse

I've created a custom environment for displaying code examples in a `beamer` presentation (for an introductory LaTeX couse no less), but compiling my "old" code suddenly results in an error. According to the old log file the version is `xparse 2011/10/09 v2900`. The definition is (slightly cleaned for brevity):

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{codeblock}{o}{
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}
        {\begin{exampleblock}{Code}}
        {\begin{exampleblock}{Code: #1}}}
{\end{exampleblock}}
```

and the error is

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! LaTeX error: "xparse/expandable-ending-optional"
! 
! Argument specification for expandable command ends with optional argument.
! 
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
```

when compiled using `xparse 2012/08/29 v4160` on my up-to-date TeX Live 2012 installation. First step in debugging this problem is to create a MWE, but this results in a quite separate error. The code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{xptest}{o}{\begin{center}
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\textbf{Test}}{\textbf{Test: #1}}\par}
  {\end{center}}

\begin{document}
\begin{xptest}[Arg]
  World
\end{xptest}

\begin{xptest}
  World
\end{xptest}
\end{document}
```

does not yield the expected result (i.e. two pieces of centered text with a bold first line) but this:

[image: Unexpected result]

I've read the documentation for my currently installed version of `xparse`, but this makes no mention of any limitation regarding terminating optional arguments. Is this a regression or expected but yet undocumented behaviour?

Comment: [This is already fixed in the SVN](https://github.com/latex3/svn-mirror/issues/107) and should be on CTAN in a few days.

Comment: Thanks. I'll wait a few days, try again and hope that the fixed version will allow terminating optional arguments.